# save config/settings into relational database (postgresql)

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I'm building a feature where I have to get/save a config (something like a json structure) into db. So this postgresql jsonb data type came into my mind. Because this config doesn't have to be related to other table. coming from a nosql background, is my use case for jsonb correct? (I don't want to abuse this feature or use it wrongly)

Is this the right thing to do? Just to double confirm with experienced dev here before I start implementing it.

Comment: Seems like a good use of a nosql DB.. why do you need to put it into an RDBMS?

Comment: @PaulHicks why not? it's a part of the app. No way I setup a new nosql db just for 1 feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a use case for `jsonb` or `json`.

These data types are useful to store information in the database that is of use for the application, but is not used much inside the database.

If you plan to use values from the JSON in queries, for example to join with other tables or to filter in `WHERE` clauses, you should consider storing these values as normal table columns (perhaps keeping the rest in a JSON).

While PostgreSQL has support for processing JSON inside the database, queries that make use of that a lot tend to become complicated and slow.

Answer (score 1):

JSON type or XML type can be used when you have not a idea about future structure. I am not sure about your case, but for configuration you can use a table:

```
CREATE TABLE config(key varchar primary key, value text);
```

and can be good enough - there is not a reason why you should to use NoSQL database. Lot of applications uses SQLite for storing configuration, so it is common usage.